# Timediff as resultset

Tags: java, sql

i'm having trouble and i'm looking for a solution.

Here's the situation : I do a query to get information from a view in my sql database, and i'm displaying it in an xls file.

The problem is that i have for the last column, I've to display the difference in hour between the "date commencement (begin date)" and the "date fin (end date)". I've already tried lot of things, but i don't find a solution. Can somebody help me ?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.mavenproject2;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
/**
 *
 * @author Stagiaire
 */
public class DataExportService {
    ConnectDB newConnectionDB = new ConnectDB();

    public void getXls() throws Exception  {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectDB con = new ConnectDB();
            PreparedStatement pst = ConnectDB.getConnection().prepareStatement("");
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM v_facture_infos WHERE real_begin_date >= DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y/%m/01' ) AND real_end_date < DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_DATE, '%Y/%m/01' )");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("test");
            HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
            rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Date commencement");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Date fin");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("Nom");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("Prénom");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("Heures");
            int i = 1;
            while (rs.next()){
                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
                row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getDate("real_begin_date"));
                row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getDate("real_end_date"));
                //query total heure avec la différence de real begin date et real end date : SELECT TIMEDIFF(@real_begin_date, @real_end_date)
                row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString("last_name"));
                row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getString("first_name"));               
                row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getString("SELECT TIMEDIFF(@real_begin_date, @real_end_date)"));
                i++;
            }
            String yemi = "C:\\Users\\Stagiaire\\Desktop\\test.xls";
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(yemi);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't execute a query like that with rs.get* - you have to write it into the SELECT statement.

Comment: well i've tried, and netbeans told me i had to many connection in the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to calculate it as part of your sql

```
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery("SELECT real_begin_date, real_end_date, first_name, last_name, TIMEDIFF(real_begin_date, real_end_date) FROM...");
```

Comment: Yes it work, thank you a lot, i've just add an AS TIME after the timediff to call it on the rs.getString. like this : SELECT real_begin_date, real_end_date, first_name, last_name, TIMEDIFF(real_begin_date, real_end_date) AS TIME FROM...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hours difference by SQL as Below :

`DATEDIFF(hour, start_date, end_date)`

If you need the number of fractional hours, you can use DATEDIFF at a higher resolution and divide the result:

```
DATEDIFF(second, start_date, end_date) / 3600.0
```